# Use & relation of weightCol in Classifiers and MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I'm learning pyspark and am currently working on an imbalanced dataset which I want to use in a classifier. Most ml classifiers support a weightCol parameter in which I can set weights for my observations. I also noticed that the [`MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator) also has a `weightCol` parameter.
I intend to use the `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` to evaluate my model.

How does `weightCol` in a classifier relate to the `weightCol` in `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator`? If I use weights in my classifier, am I supposed to pass the same column in `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` when I want to obtain accuracy or other metrics?